# Wildcard in Angular http.get?

Tags: json, angularjs, get

I have multiple JSON files in one directory, and I am going to build the view contents from those JSON files. The JSON files are identical in structure.

What is the correct syntax for loading multiple JSON files for use with `ng-repeat`? I tried with this, but it throws a permission denied error (the view is loaded via a route, if it matters. Still learning Angular...).

I use these:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Snippet from the view:

```
<div ng-controller="releases">
    <article ng-repeat="album in albums">
        {{ album.artist }}
    </article>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('releases', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.albums = [];
    $http.get('contents/releases/*.json')
    .then(function(releases) {
        $scope.albums = releases.data;
        console.log($scope.albums);
    });
});
```

The JSON files are like this:

```
{
    "artist" : "Artist name",
    "album" : "Album title",
    "releaseDate" : "2015-09-16"
}
```

The error message is:

`You don't have permission to access /mypage/angular/contents/releases/*.json on this server.`

If I use an exact filename, for example `$http.get('contents/releases/album.json')`, I can access the data correctly. But naturally only for one JSON, instead of the 11 files I have.

In a previous site I have done with PHP, I used an identical method, and there I could access the same files with no problem. For both, I'm using WAMP server (Apache 2) as the platform.

Could it still have something to do with the Apache config? The reason I don't think it is that, is because it does work in PHP like this:

```
// Get release data
$releasesDataLocation = 'contents/releases/*.json';
$releasesDataFiles = glob($releasesDataLocation);
rsort($releasesDataFiles); // Rsort = newest release first, comment out to show oldest first

// Show the releases
foreach($releasesDataFiles as $releaseData) {
    $release = new Release($releaseData);
    $release->display();
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking is it better to simply concatenate the JSON files into one bigger one at the source, so that there exists just one JSON file at all. Similar to what Ashutosh Upadhyay suggests in the answer? It might save some requests, as the file itself is still quite small (24 KB).

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard AFAIK in such URLs is not allowed. You should build a server side endpoint that should read all the files in your directory on server, concatenate and return the response to you.

For eX: you could expose a GET URL: /api/contents/releases
and server side handler of it can read the directory containing all release JSONs and return to you.